# SQL/JPA Criteria query for inheritance object model using AND

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, criteria-api

Given is the following database table (based on JPA object model):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | type | stringValue |      dateValue    | booleanValue| relationObject_id|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | strg | Some string |       NULL        |    NULL     |        200       |
| 2  | bool |    NULL     |       NULL        |     1       |        200       |
| 3  | str  | Some string |       NULL        |    NULL     |        210       |
| 4  | bool |    NULL     |       NULL        |     1       |        210       |
| 5  | date |    NULL     | 2016-03-01 00:00  |    NULL     |        210       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try to define a query using the `Criteria API` that

- lists all `RelationObject` items containing the `stringValue` 'Some string' **AND** `booleanValue` = 1
- only lists those `RelationObject` items where both parameters apply

The query that is generated by Hibernate looks approximately as follows:

`SELECT
     DISTINCT RelationObject.id,
 FROM
     RelationObject

 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     RelationObject

     ON RelationObject.id=ConcreteValue.relationObject_id 
 WHERE
         ConcreteValue.stringValue like '%Some string%'
     AND ConcreteValue.booleanValue=1`

This is exactly where the mistake lies: According to the data model there is (of course) no `RelationObject` that has `ConcreteValue.stringValue like '%Some string%' AND ConcreteValue.booleanValue=1` in one single tuple as the values belonging to one single `relationObject_id` are split up on different tuples.

I cannot come up with an adequate solution. I look for a simple SQL query or, even better, a `CriteriaQuery` that matches the requirement.

The table definition is a result of the following JPA model:

```
@Entity
public class RelationObject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="relationObject", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ConcreteValue> concreteValues;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class ConcreteValue implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn
    private RelationObject relationObject;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("bool")
public class ConcreteBooleanValue extends ValueEntry implements Serializable {

    private Boolean booleanValue;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("strg")
public class ConcreteStringValue extends ValueEntry implements Serializable {

    private String stringValue;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("date")
public class ConcreteDateValue extends ValueEntry implements Serializable {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateValue;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: There is none, either `stringValue` is `null` or `booleanValue` is `null`, because they are defined in sibling subclasses. Please, post you real code or the correct equivalent of it.

Comment: @philipxy Please see my comment to your answer below.

Comment: Thanks for confirming in a comment that you want "those where exactly both parameters match". Please read about MCVEs in the help center.